# Python: Parse String for Tags to divide it into substrings to fill json files

Tags: python, string, dictionary

'**Q:**
How do i check if a text file contains all tags (for example predifned in a lookup table) and then parse all substrings that appear between these tags and use them to fill a new json file.

Example Text file:

```
# AB C: 
definition of ab c
## DEF: definition of def
### GHI: 
definition of ghi
more defintion of ghi
a tricky : appears in this defintion
```

Example tag Look-up table:

```
# AB C : ab c
## DEF : def
### GHI : ghi
## JKL : jkl
```

Desired json output:

```
{
 'ab c': 'definition of ab c',
 'def': 'definition of def',
 'ghi': 'definition of ghi',
 'jkl': ''
}
> Warning: Tag '## JKL' is missing
```

**Approach So Far:**
Create Two Tag Dictionaries, one like the example look-up table and the second with values of the first as keys and empty strings as values.

```
text = '''# AB C: 
        definition of ab c
        ## DEF: definition of def
        ### GHI: 
        definition of ghi
        more defintion of ghi
        a tricky : appears in this defintion'''

lookup = {
    '# AB C' : 'ab c',
    '## DEF' : 'def',
    '### GHI' : 'ghi',
    '## JKL' : 'jkl',
    }
lookup_rev = {
    'ab c' : '',
    'def' : '',
    'ghi' : '',
    'jkl' : '',
    }
```

But I dont know how to check a string for substrings (the tags) and the extract the substrings trailing each tag.

> IMPORTANT 1: the tags can include white space, so something like: '## AB C'. Furthermore the exact number of hastags is important and needs to be included in the look up
>
> IMPORTANT 2: the definitons may be multi line and ':' may also appear in a definition, so this is not a save split point

Comment: show what you have done so far please

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "parse all substrings that lie between these tags", what are you parsing and what are the tags in this example? What's the logic behind the multiple "#" in your example file?

Comment: it is a markdown file @elelias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lookup = {
    '# AB C' : 'ab c',
    '## DEF' : 'def',
    '### GHI' : 'ghi',
    '## JKL' : 'jkl',
}

text_file = '''# AB C:
        definition of ab c
        ## DEF: definition of def
        ### GHI:
        definition of ghi
        more defintion of ghi
        a tricky : appears in this defintion'''

import re

d = {k: '' for k in lookup}
d.update(re.findall(r'^\s*([#]+\s+[A-Z][A-Z\s]*[A-Z])\s*:(.*?)(?=^\s*#|\Z)', text_file, flags=re.M|re.DOTALL))
d = {lookup[k]:v.strip() for k, v in d.items()}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)
print(*['> Warning: Tag {} is missing'.format(k) for k, v in d.items() if not v])
```

Prints:

```
{'ab c': 'definition of ab c',
 'def': 'definition of def',
 'ghi': 'definition of ghi\n'
        '        more defintion of ghi\n'
        '        a tricky : appears in this defintion',
 'jkl': ''}
> Warning: Tag jkl is missing
```

Comment: Multiline is not supported, and ':' inside the definition do mess it up as well.

Comment: Last update to the text: The tags may include white spaces (e.g. # AB C) This still causes an error, sorry for often changing the example. Finally is it possible to do it without the lookup_table string, but just with the lookup dict?

Comment: @gustavz Yes, it's possible. See my answer.